# xcode13でiOS16のシミュレータを動かす方法

Tags: ios, xcode

取り急ぎ、開発中のアプリをiOS16で動作確認したいです。

以下の代案は見つかったのですが、xcode13のまま実現させる方法が見つからず。。
・シミュレータではなく開発用デバイスにiOS16を入れる
・1台のPCにxcode14を入れて旧バージョンと共存させる（最終的にはこれで動作確認予定）

例えば、.xcode-versionを修正みたいな形で実現させる方法はないでしょうか。
知っている方がいればお願いします。

Comment: 参考: [How can I build an app with XCode 13.4 for iOS 16 Devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73196012/2322778)

Comment: 上記リンクはデバイス上で動かす方法でしょうか？出来ればシミュレータ上で動かしたいです。